# How to create a custom MySQL query to display WordPress posts (no wpquery)?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I wanted to create a Java application which displays WordPress posts.
So is there any way I can display WordPress posts without `wp_query` using actual MySQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the query according your usage.

```
$querystr = "
        SELECT wp_posts.* 
        FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
        WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
        AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'tag' 
        AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'email' 
        AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
        AND wp_posts.post_date < NOW()
        ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
     ";
```

Comment: Thanks @Jay you saved the day

Comment: @KeshavThosar Welcome.

Comment: Is there any way I can display the posts of a certain category